# What's the point of using (x < n || x > n) instead of (x != n)?

Tags: c

What's the point of performing two comparisons resulting in two jumps (jl and jle) instead of performing one comparison (!=) resulting in one jump (je)?

Comment: You mean `x < n || x > n`?

Comment: Your expressions are not equivalent...

Comment: "I see a lot of C conditionals" -- citations needed. Where do you see them? Can you give a few examples? Are they in open source projects in the wild? Are they written by a specific colleague?

Comment: What's the datatype of `x`?

Comment: What is the type of 'x'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a compiler expert but I believe that code would be equivalent to `x != n && x != n+1`. Assuming integer-like type. And, if it's float-like type then they are obviously not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're asking, guy: "Why wouldn't you just write x isnotequal n instead of x greater than n, x less than n?" I've seen this being used in guessing games before, where if the user guess less/greater than n, the values lower/higher than x would be removed.